# CSS3 column-count: 2 + height: 100% cut off images

Tags: css, column-count

In the process of displaying a bunch of paragraph <p> elements with quite a few <div> mixed-in, so they are shown nicely with the effect of an opened book, I set <html> to

```
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

and <body> to

```
body {
  column-count: 2;
  height: 100%;
}
```

They all work nicely except the images are cut off and display to "next page", i.e., pictures are split to display in 2 columns.

I tried setting

```
img {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

in attempt to reinstate the image's integrity, but without luck. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Doesn't seem to be an issue in Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/LJ9Jz/

Comment: Thanks for replying, Passerby; actually, with that convenient link of yours, please increase your image to 100x700 and add in the clause, html{width:100%;height:100%} which I've forgotten, and you will see what I meant.  I want a rule that would shrink the image nicely to fit the height of the window un-broken, if it's possible.

Comment: You can update the fiddle and post it to your question so others can see and play with it themselves; this may be a good demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/LJ9Jz/11/ I noticed that Firefox 19 doesn't break the image, but results in 3 columns.

Comment: It seems there is no good solution as of May 31st. So I'm just gonna go ahead and say I just constrained the image width by estimation and set the height on auto. At least that works for the most cases...